# Windows torrent client with labeling feature

Tags: windows-7, bittorrent, label

I'm looking for an torrent client, that knows where to put downloaded files based on label...

Examples:

- I'm downloading "ubuntu 11.04" which I labeled **linux** and I want that this is saved on C:\linux.
- I'm downloading "windows 7" which I labeled **windows** and I want that this is saved on C:\windows.

Do you know some torrent client that knows to do that?

Comment: Uhhm, I hope in your second example you meant "Fedora 15" (or *anything* but not a commercial software you don't want to pay for).

Comment: Is just an example... but how could fedora be labeled windows?... btw download windows can be legal, if you download it from microsoft... I have legal windows downloaded from MSDAA ;)

Comment: Then you might label it "fedora". You know what I mean. However, I don't recall Microsoft releasing torrents of their software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/)

For what it's worth, there's uTorrent, which also has a labeling feature. You can organize your downloads according to labels you can set before. Here's [a guide on that](http://torrentfreak.com/use-utorrent-to-organize-your-bittorrent-downloads/).

[image]

Go to Option → Preferences → Advanced → user_interface. Here you can enter a set of persistent labels for the downloads. Separate them with a pipe `|`.

Then, go to Options → Preferences → Downloads and tick the "Append the torrent’s label to the directory name" box.